# Multiplying column and row vectors in Numpy

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I'd like to multiply two vectors, one column (i.e., (N+1)x1), one row (i.e., 1x(N+1)) to give a (N+1)x(N+1) matrix. I'm fairly new to Numpy but have some experience with MATLAB, this is the equivalent code in MATLAB to what I want in Numpy:

```
n = 0:N; 
xx = cos(pi*n/N)';
T = cos(acos(xx)*n');
```

in Numpy I've tried:

```
import numpy as np
n = range(0,N+1)

pi = np.pi
xx = np.cos(np.multiply(pi / float(N), n))

xxa = np.asarray(xx)
na = np.asarray(n)
nd = np.transpose(na)

T = np.cos(np.multiply(np.arccos(xxa),nd))
```

I added the asarray line after I noticed that without it Numpy seemed to be treating xx and n as lists. `np.shape(n)`, `np.shape(xx)`, `np.shape(na)` and `np.shape(xxa)` gives the same result: `(100001L,)`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`np.multiply`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html) only does element by element multiplication.  You want an outer product.  Use [`np.outer`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html):

```
np.outer(np.arccos(xxa), nd)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use NumPy similar to MATLAB, you have to make sure that your arrays have the right shape. You can check the shape of any NumPy array with `arrayname.shape` and because your array `na` has shape `(4,)` instead of `(4,1)`, the `transpose` method is effectless and `multiply` calculates the dot product. Use `arrayname.reshape(N+1,1)` resp. `arrayname.reshape(1,N+1)` to transform your arrays:

```py
import numpy as np

n = range(0,N+1)
pi = np.pi
xx = np.cos(np.multiply(pi / float(N), n))

xxa = np.asarray(xx).reshape(N+1,1)
na = np.asarray(n).reshape(N+1,1)
nd = np.transpose(na)

T = np.cos(np.multiply(np.arccos(xxa),nd))
```

Since Python 3.5, you can use the `@` operator for matrix multiplication. So it's a walkover to get code that's very similar to MATLAB:

```py
import numpy as np

n = np.arange(N + 1).reshape(N + 1, 1)   
xx = np.cos(np.pi * n / N)
T = np.cos(np.arccos(xx) @ n.T)
```

Here `n.T` denotes the transpose of n.